# Process one or multiple objects from a list

Tags: shell-script, shell, zsh, freebsd, for

I wrote a script that will find objects that contain spaces in the name, and replaces each space with an underscore. The object type is based on a single object selection.
How can I process all object-types as an alternative option? I was thinking maybe an if-then-else along with and inner for loop?

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "Choose object from the list below\n"
printf "**policy**\n**ipadd**r\n**subnet**\n**netmap**\n**netgroup**\n
**host**\n**iprange**\n**zonegroup**\n" | tee object.txt

read object
IFS="`printf '\n\t'`"
#   Find all selected object names that contain spaces
cf -TJK name "$object" q | tail -n +3 |sed 's/ *$//' |grep " " >temp
for x in `cat temp`
do
#   Assign the y variable to the new name
y=`printf "$x" | tr ' ' '_'`
#   Rename the object using underscores
cf "$object" modify name="$x" newname="$y"
done
```

Comment: Please also provide the output of `cf -TJK name $object q | tail -n +3 |sed 's/ *$//' |grep " "` with any object, redacted if needed but it would help to see the format of that output.

Comment: @Steve : Why not using an array, for instance `set -A all policy netgroup .....` ?

Comment: YES, an array would help and it does work in KSH. Originally I thought it didn;'t because unless I execute the script with <ksh file name.sh> it errored out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to present a menu to your user, think of the `select` command:

```
#  Ask the user which object type they would like to rename
objects=( policy netgroup zonegroup host iprange ipaddr subnet netmap )
PS3="Which network object type would you like to edit? "

select object in "${objects[@]}" all; do
    [[ -n "$object" ]] && break
done

if [[ "$object" == "all" ]]; then
    # comma separated list of all objects
    object=$( IFS=,; echo "${objects[*]}" )
fi

cf -TJK name "$object" q | etc etc etc
# ...........^ get into the habit of quoting your variables.
```

I'm assuming [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) here. Let us know if that's not the shell you're using.

---

If you're stuck in a shell without arrays, you can do this since the objects are simple words:

```
objects="policy netgroup zonegroup host iprange ipaddr subnet netmap"
PS3="Which network object type would you like to edit? "

select object in $objects all; do     # $objects is specifically not quoted here ...
    [ -n "$object" ] && break
done

if [ "$object" = "all" ]; then
    object=$( set -- $objects; IFS=,; echo "$*" )        # ... or here
fi

cf -TJK name "$object" q | etc etc etc
```

Comment: I am using a bastardized version of freebsd in a sidewinder firewall appliance.  In essence of what you provided, yes, but this OS doesn't recognize the @ symbol with the brackets. the variable "all" would run a command against the first object-type, then the second and so on.

Comment: no sir, this appliance does not have bash. It has tcsh, ksh, sh, csh, and zsh

Comment: what version of ksh? `ksh --version` returns what?

Comment: and the "OS" has nothing to do with the shell.

Comment: but the command will not run multiple variables simultaneously,just 1  cf policy modify name="$x" newname="$y"
cf ipaddr modify name="$x" newname="$y"
cf iprange modify name="$x" newname="$y"
cf subnet modify name="$x" newname="$y"
cf netgroup modify name="$x" newname="$y"
cf netmap modify name="$x" newname="$y"
cf host modify name="$x" newname="$y"
cf zonegroup modify name="$x" newname="$y"

Comment: version         builtins.c,v 1.3 2011/07/25 13:16:39 srasappa Exp

Comment: hmm. ksh93 has arrays. don't know about ksh88. zsh does but I'm not that familiar with zsh syntax. It's really odd that your system has all those shells but not bash.

Comment: `man zshparam` explains that associative arrays can be assigned and used like so: `typeset -A x; x=(key1 value1 key2 value2 foo bar ); echo "${x[foo]}"`, which outputs "*bar*".

Comment: You did not specify exactly what should happen in the "all" case. Here I just used a comma separated string. If something else should be done, either do that or tell us what you want to do

Comment: @agc we don't need associative array here, just a plain indexed array. What needs to be changed in my first snippet to be valid zsh?

Comment: @glennjackman, The first snippet works correctly in `zsh` without changes.

Comment: @glenn jackman, the biggest conflict I am having is the specifics of this appliance and its proprietary command set. It is a Sidewinder firewall using its own customized version of freebsd and no BASH. My script works when processing a single object like "policy". There are 8 different objects possible. I would like to have an "all" option that will loop through all 8 possible objects. I think I can re-write the question negating a lot of specific commands to make it less confusing

Comment: The function of the script is to identify objects with spaces in the name, and replace the spaces with underscores

Comment: The array worked, it just took a while as this was my first time ever creating an array. The ksh syntax was different. I used `set -A objects policy subnet ipaddr netgroup iprange host netmap zonegroup` for the array, I declared ksh as my shell in the script but I also has to run the script using ksh filename versus what I have always used sh filename. Still learning more and more everyday . Thanks for all the help